# Set Permissions to Test Plans only

Tags: permissions, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, test-plan

I'm currently searching for a way to grant specific users permissions to only use and manage the features listed ind the Test Plans tab in azure devops. So users in this group/team should not be able to see releases, builds, code and all the other stuff in the current project.

Is there a Way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: On which level are these permissions set? I can't find these setting anywhere (not on project settings and also not on admin settings).

Comment: The screenshot in my example is navigating to the `Security` tab in `Project Settings` -- `Repositories`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#tfvc-object-level. You can check more information describing each built-in security user and group as well as each permission in the link below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Comment: Are you able to set the permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to disable services of Repos, Pipeline, etc. You need to set the permission for each resource by referring to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

For example, make users not see the repo, you can deny the "Read" permission for the repo:

[image]